# ClassNotFoundException for android.telephony.SubscriptionManager in android

Tags: android, classnotfoundexception, telephonymanager

I just complied a program in android. Iam getting the following error. How to solve this please reply me as soon as possible!

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug'.

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.telephony.SubscriptionManager

Comment: That class was added in Android 5.1. What version of Android are you running your app on?

Comment: I am using 4.4.2 i.e. kitkat. can i generate apk and test on this device ?

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to use a class that does not exist on the version of Android that you are using. `android.telephony.SubscriptionManager` was added in Android 5.1. Your test device is older than that.

Your build tools should be pointing out this incompatibility to you.

> can i generate apk and test on this device ?

No. Either stop using this class (and anything else newer than Android 4.4, API Level 19) or get a test device that runs Android 5.1 (API Level 22). Ordinarily, an emulator would be an option, but for `android.telephony` classes, my guess is that you will get more accurate results with hardware.